# Slack API: How to determine botname in an app_mention message?

Tags: slack-api

I was looking at https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention as a mechanism to subscribe to messages sent to my bot that would be processed by my app.

An example payload on that page is shown as:

```
{
    "token": "ZZZZZZWSxiZZZ2yIvs3peJ",
    "team_id": "T061EG9R6",
    "api_app_id": "A0MDYCDME",
    "event": {
        "type": "app_mention",
        "user": "U061F7AUR",
        "text": "What is the hour of the pearl, <@U0LAN0Z89>?",
        "ts": "1515449522.000016",
        "channel": "C0LAN2Q65",
        "event_ts": "1515449522000016"
    },
    "type": "event_callback",
    "event_id": "Ev0LAN670R",
    "event_time": 1515449522000016,
    "authed_users": [
        "U0LAN0Z89"
    ]
}
```

I'd like to strip out the botname in the message, <@U0LAN0Z89> in this case, but I don't simply want to regex out any <@mentions>, just the bot.

Can I count on ID belonging to the bot to be in authed_users? Or is there another way for my app to get the ID of the bot that is sending it messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From how I've read your message, sounds like you want to get a couple of different pieces of information from the event, so I'll cover them both as best I can. Feel free to just ignore any false assumptions.

First off, the `authed_users` field. *Best that I can tell*, your assumption is correct, but I amn't 100% on this.

To be absolutely confident you're stripping out the right ID, you can parse the `event.text` field, and for each value, call `users.info`. Inside of `users.info`, you'll see a `user.profile.api_app_id` field. The one that matches your App ID is *definitely* your bot.

The second bit of your question I wasn't sure about was

> get the ID of the bot that is sending it messages

Assuming you want to get the UID of the person who created the message that fired the event, what you want there is the `event.user` field.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this same behavior while dealing with `authed_users` in a `link_shared` event. That lists would contain only the bot user id regardless of how many users had authenticated with the app.

Then I noticed I had the `link_shared` event under **Bot Events**. After moving it to **Workspace events** in the app configuration page, now it gets the actual list of authenticated users without the bot id.

Hopefully this could throw some light on the issue.